# Clearing all DataSet Bookmarks

Tags: delphi, bookmarks, delphi-5

About one time in maybe a hundred of running a D5 program it tosses an "Invalid Bookmark," error. Clicking "OK" in the error message dialog moves past it and the system operates fine.

This app has about 20 TDBGrids in it and all of them at salient points have "Clear" to clear the Bookmarks. There are 17 DataSets.

Because it is so rare, and I suspect as a result of something the user has done (not their fault) just before shutting down, it is proving very difficult to find and fix.

Is there anyway I can bulk clear all bookmarks across all DataSets at start up?

I have been reading here that Bookmarks are supposed to be cleared on "Open/Close" and all DataSets are Opened at start up.

```
If Table1.Active then Table1.Close;  // They should never be Active but...
Table.Open;
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Bookmarks are memory structures used to direct point to records. They are not persistent so in fact they are all cleared everytime a dataset is closed. I suspect that your problem is that when a record is deleted, there is still a bookmark created to it and dataset will keep an invalid reference to that record. In older versions of Delphi the programmer is still responsible for disposing Bookmarks by calling TDataset.FreeBookmark when it´s not needed anymore. The programmer is also responsible for disposing a bookmark to a record before it is deleted from the dataset.

Comment: @AlexSC: Indeed.  The "Marking and returning to records" in the D5 OLH doesn't spell out that they become invalid when the dataset is closed. Imo, if the OP wants to return to a record after that, it's safer to get at it via a unique key.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to bulk-delete Bookmarks for a TDataSet. You have to free them one by one.

Side note: When using Bookmarks you need to be very careful, after any change (insert, update or delete) in the TDataset your bookmarks are not valid any more (often they will still work, but officially they are out of date and need to be refreshed).